# How to find if a user has connected another HD via SATA or IDE?

Tags: windows, forensics

I need to find a registry place that can give me the necessary information to know if someone has connected another (in addition to the current one) HD (SATA or IDE) to the computer.

Is there a program that can tell me that information ?

I have found a place in the registry that include all the info about the [MountedDevices](http://eptuners.com/forensics/contents/examination.htm#Mounted%20Devices:), but as far as i can see it isn't acuurate (at least on my system), and it doesn't give me any clue about the Serial number of the connected device.

I would like to get as much information as possibole about the connected device.

Windows-OS.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to remotely detect what hardware is currently installed in a machine? Or do you have the machine and are trying to detect if hardware has previously been installed and later removed?

Comment: I am trying to detect if hardware (SATA or IDE) has been inserted without my confirmation.

Comment: The Volume Serial Number can often be found in MountedDevices

Answer (score 1):

The information in MountedDevices is accurate. However, it is not consistent across Windows versions. See also `HKLM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\IDE` for additional information, which must be crossreferenced.

Windows (XP at least) does not store the serial number of HDDs.